# Does TFS under the VS2012 shell offer more than limited access?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am using VS2010 with access to TFS via the VS2012 shell. Looking around on the web version that usually offers rich functionality I am unable to view the kanban board and graphs. Will I need a higher level of access or does this installation not allow these?

Answer (score 0):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997788.aspx:

"When you connect to a more recent version of TFS than that of the client that you run, you’ll only be able to access those features supported by your client. For example, if you connect Visual Studio 2010 to TFS 2013, you can perform the same functions as if you connected to TFS 2010. You can’t access any new features that Visual Studio 2010 doesn’t support."

Comment: Ah I see, so TFS2010 doesn't have the board and burn down graphs?

Comment: I believe both are new in TFS 2012 and of course are now in 2013. You can view burndowns via reports though if you have that functionality available.